# How to create a dictionary contains the summation of the keys for the first dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am working on a CSV file. I am looking to make summation of all case numbers for each day of week and put them in a list of dictionaries.

The list of dictionaries should be:

```
T = [{'Saturday', total number of cases}, {'Sunday', total number of cases}, {'Monday', total number of cases}, .... ]
```

That what I did, but it doesn't work:

```
with open('DataCleaning.csv') as f:

    data = [{k: str(v) for k, v in row.items()}

        for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]

Case_Count_Saturday = {}

for row in data:

    if 'Saturday' in row["dayofweek_name"]:

        k = row['CASE_COUNT']

        if k in Case_Count_Saturday.keys():

            Case_Count_Saturday[k] += 1

        else:

            Case_Count_Saturday[k] = 1

print(Case_Count_Saturday)

Case_Count_Saturday1 = {}

for case, count in Case_Count_Saturday.items():

    k = "saterday"

    if k in Case_Count_Saturday1.keys():

        Case_Count_Saturday1[k] += 1

    else:

        Case_Count_Saturday1[k] = 1

print(Case_Count_Saturday1)
```

This is part of the dataset:

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand the whole question, but if you just want to convert the keys of one of the dictionaries to int and sum them, then just do `sum(map(int, your_dictionary.keys()))`

Comment: I just need to know what I should change in my code above to be the day of week is the key of the dictionary and summation of all cases is the value of this dictionary. The first dictionary  "Case_Count_Saturday " should do that, but it didn't. The first dictionary gave me the summation of cases are the keys of this dictionary and the count of each case is the value for each key and that what I don't want that. The question now. what should I do in the first part of my code or my first dictionary "Case_Count_Saturday" to get a dictionary like that > {'Saturday': summation of all case numbers}?

Comment: Do you want me to re-write my question to be more clear to you?

Comment: Yeah. You can also include (part) of your CSV file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest. I include part of my CSV file.

Comment: "That what I did, but it doesn't work:". What happens instead?

Comment: I am still trying to solve this problem and I need your help if you can